# Images not showing on surface in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, surface, blit

I am attempting to make a game with two surfaces. However when I try and add an image to the game layer it doesn't show up. I have tried using `pygame.display.flip()` which, from what I understand, should update everything on the screen.

If I try to use either `Game_Layer.update()` or `Game_Layer.flip()` as seen in the code below... (I think `Game_Layer.flip()` doesn't work because `.flip` is used to update the entire screen and thus can't be called for specific layers but correct me if I am wrong).

```
#game play
def Dragon():
    DragonIMG=pygame.image.load("Green Dragon.gif")
    DragonIMG.convert()    
    global Game_Layer
    x=0
    y=0
    Game_Layer.blit(DragonIMG,(x,y))
    Game_Layer.update()
Dragon()
```

I get the following error message:

```
 RESTART: C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive\A- Levels\1 COMPUTER SCIENCE\Course work\Coding\CSCW Pre Alfa 1.9.5.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive\A- Levels\1 COMPUTER SCIENCE\Course work\Coding\CSCW Pre Alfa 1.9.5.py", line 133, in <module>
    Dragon()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive\A- Levels\1 COMPUTER SCIENCE\Course work\Coding\CSCW Pre Alfa 1.9.5.py", line 131, in Dragon
    Game_Layer.update()
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'update'
>>>
```

However when I try to display an image on the root layer using the code below it works.

```
#game play
def Dragon():
    DragonIMG=pygame.image.load("Green Dragon.gif")
    DragonIMG.convert()    
    global Base_Layer
    x=0
    y=0
    Base_Layer.blit(DragonIMG,(x,y))
    pygame.display.flip()
Dragon()
```

Below is the code I am using to set up the layers:

```
#libraries
import time, random, pygame, sqlite3, GIFimage2
pygame.init()



#screen setup
#variables 
clock=pygame.time.Clock()               #for use in .tick
black=pygame.color.Color("black")       #set black
white=pygame.color.Color("white")       #set white
#set up the base layer 
Base_Layer=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))          #desplay setup
pygame.display.set_caption("Dragon King: Legacy")       #set caption
black=(0,0,0)                                           #colour set
Base_Layer.fill(black)                                  #colour set
Base_Layer.convert()                                    #converts the base layer, may have no effect in current position
icon=pygame.image.load("LOGO.png")                      #find logo
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)                           #set icon to logo
#set up the game layer        
Game_Layer=pygame.Surface((600,600))    #set layer peramaters
Game_Layer.fill(white)                  #set layer to white
Game_Layer.convert()                    #converts the game layer, may have no effect in current position
Base_Layer.blit(Game_Layer, (10, 0))    #blit layer on to screen
pygame.display.flip()                   #get the layer to show
```

If anyone could explain to me why this is not working I would appreciate it. I would also appreciate if someone knows a way to display my images in the way I am currently (within a definition) without using global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pygame programs are usually structured similarly to the following example. First of all, initialize everything and load the images and other resources (do that only once ahead of the main loop), then, in the main `while` loop, handle the events, update the game and blit everything. Finally, call `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()` to make all changes visible and `clock.tick(fps)` to limit the frame rate.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
# Constants (use uppercase letters to signal that these shouldn't be modified).
BLACK = pygame.color.Color("black")
WHITE = pygame.color.Color("white")

GAME_LAYER = pygame.Surface((600, 600))
GAME_LAYER.fill(WHITE)
# convert() returns a new surface, so you have to assign it to a variable.
DRAGON_IMG = pygame.image.load("Green Dragon.gif").convert()


def main(screen):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    # Variables
    x = 0
    y = 0

    while True:
        # Handle events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        # Game logic.
        x += 1

        # Clear the screen and blit everything.
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        screen.blit(GAME_LAYER, (10, 0))
        screen.blit(DRAGON_IMG, (x, y))

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(screen)
    pygame.quit()
```

If you want to blit onto a background surface instead of the screen/display and it's unicolored, you can just fill the background surface each frame with the `fill` method, then blit the dragon and finally blit the background onto the screen:

```
game_layer.fill(WHITE)
game_layer.blit(DRAGON_IMG, (x, y))
screen.blit(game_layer, (10, 0))
```

Or if your background surface is an actual image, you can create a copy each frame and then blit onto this copy:

```
game_layer_copy = GAME_LAYER.copy()
game_layer_copy.blit(DRAGON_IMG, (x, y))
screen.blit(game_layer_copy, (10, 0))
```

Comment: Hello skrx. thank you fat taking the time to answer my question. I fear I may not have been clear in my question. I was hopping to get images to display on the second surface and not on the root surface, as you have done. is there a way to do this? I have tried using the same syntax used to get the image to display on the root layer, and applied it to the secondary layer but I doesn't work. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: So you want to blit the `DRAGON_IMG` onto a background surface (`GAME_LAYER`) and then the background surface onto the screen? That's a bit problematic because blitting changes the surface permanently. If you want to avoid this, you'd have to make a copy of the background surface each frame and then blit onto the copy. Or just `.fill` the `GAME_LAYER` each frame if it's unicolored.

Answer (score 1):

Game_Layer is a surface, and surfaces have no update method. update is a function of pygame.display. `pygame.display.update` is like `pygame.display.flip` except you can specify what parts of the screen should be flipped.

Also, please don't use `global` if you have any other choice. It's considered better to wrap everything into a class, pass `Game_Layer` as a argument, or use `pygame.display.get_surface()`